# How do I save a custom size screenshot on python?

Tags: python

So I'm working on the little project and the problem I ran to is... I can take a screenshot with custom size but I cannot save it to disk. What should I do?

`import pyautogui as ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.screenshot(region=(0,0,300,400)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the solution is:

im.save('test.png')